# What are the bounds in integrating this joint density function?

Tags: probability

The joint density function is $f(x,y) = 6e^{-2x-3y}$

The question asks to find $P(X\leq x , Y \leq y)$

I know that I have to integrate over the region bound by the density function, but I'm not sure what the bounded area is.

My current guess is $\int_{x = 0}^{x = x}\int_{y = 0}^{y = y}6e^{-2x-3y} dydx$

where the upper bound is $x$ and $y$ and the lower bound is $0$. But I don't think this is the case and there has to be a numerical solution to the problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: $P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_x(t)dt$ and $P(X\geq x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f_x(t)dt$ Is that helpful?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the same variable name for both the dummy variable and the "real" variable.

Comment: not really, X and x don't represent the same variables

Comment: If you were finding $P(X\leq2,Y\leq3)$, then what region would you integrate over (draw a diagram!)?

Comment: What, if anything, makes you doubt your current guess?
P.S.: I agree with Brian Tung, it would be better if you used, say, $u$ and $v$ in your integration, since $x$ and $y$ are meant to be some given constants in this question.